horizontal spacing between subplots
I would like to increase the horizontal spacing between two subplots, otherwise the ylabel of the second one (the right one) overlaps with the right plot itself (I prefer to do that rather than change the font sizes). Here is a sample code:
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

x = np.arange(0,1,0.01)

y = x**2

z = x**3

fig = plt.figure('Sample')


plt.subplot(2,2,1)

   
plt.xlabel("$x$", fontsize=33)

plt.ylabel("My function", fontsize=33)  

plt.plot(x, y)

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(),fontsize=26)

ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(),fontsize=26)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f')) 


plt.subplot(2,2,2)

   
plt.xlabel("$x$", fontsize=33)

plt.ylabel("My function 2", fontsize=33)  

plt.plot(x, z)

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(),fontsize=26)

ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(),fontsize=26)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f')) 

Is there a simple way to achieve this?
I tried to use "fig.tight_layout()" but it had no effect

Regarding the duplicate, specifically see this answer, which uses subplots_adjust.

Thank you for these responses. I would appreciate knowing the correct way of using these in my code, as I tried either "plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.9)" or "fig.tight_layout()" and have seen no effect. Where would you use it in my code. Thanks

An important problem is that your text sizes are extremely large compared to the figsize. Normally, fig.tight_layout() would work in your case. It needs to be called near the end of code, when all labels and their sizes are fixed. If you want to add extra horizontal space after fig.tight_layout(), you can call fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.99). The maximum for hspace is 1, which makes the horizontal space between the subplots equal to the size of the subplots. (fig.subplots_adjust(right=...) is meant for the right of the "page", at the right of all subplots.)

To set the fontsize of the tick labels, you should use ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=26).  The ticks and their labels are only created at the moment of plotting, when the limits and sizes are fixed.

Also, the "modern" (i.e., since many years), recommended way to create the plots is not fig = plt.figure() with plt.subplot(2,2,1), but instead something like fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5)). Note that the default figsize is usually very small (like (6.4, 4.8)), which doesn't fit many subplots. See also difference between drawing plots using plot, axes or figure.

@JohanC Thank you so much for the comments. When I use fig.tight_layout() toward the end of the code, it does work. The problem is that the spacing is too large, and also it distorts the numbers on the x-axis, so that because the subplot is pushed to the right, the numbers in xticklabels overlap each other. If I use fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.99) I don't see it having any effect, whether I use it in addition or instead of fig.tight_layout(), also at the end of the code, so I wonder if I am using it incorrectly.

What's incorrect is the size of the text font compared to the figure size.  tight_layout() can't change that. The hspace is already at its maximum. You either need a smaller font, or a larger figsize.
